# Can I retrieve data just from columns whose names have in another table a certain property

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables products and column_names as follows:

products

```
+----+------+-----------+--------------+-------+
| id | code | category  | description  | link  |
+----+------+-----------+--------------+-------+
| 1  | 1111 | category1 | description1 | link1 |
| 2  | 2222 | category1 | description2 | link2 |
| 3  | 3333 | category1 | description3 | link3 |
| 4  | 4444 | category2 | description4 | link4 |
| 5  | 5555 | category2 | description5 | link5 |
| 6  | 6666 | category3 | description6 | link6 |
+----+------+-----------+--------------+-------+
```

column_names

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | column      | type  |
+----+-------------+-------+
| 1  | id          | type1 |
| 2  | code        | type1 |
| 3  | category    | type2 |
| 4  | description | type2 |
| 5  | link        | type3 |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

I can make this statement:

```
SELECT ( SELECT `column` FROM `column_names` WHERE `column_id` = 3) FROM `products` WHERE `id` = 1
```

while I cannot get this statement:

```
SELECT ( SELECT `column` FROM `column_names` WHERE `type` = 'type2') FROM `products` WHERE `id` = 1
```

It gives me error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

But is it possible to perform query like that? Namely, I would like to extract data just of certain columns in the products table that have certain type in the column_names table.

Is this the right design of the tables or should there be another approach? Of course category should be in another table but this is not what I am asking.

Thank you very much!

Comment: In order to do this, you need dynamic SQL.  Such variable selection of columns is not often used.

Comment: check     SET @sql = CONCAT('    '); PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; EXECUTE stmt; I think this is what you need

Comment: Thanks to both! Dynamic SQL then - I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) and [A Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2325987/a-paul) I was able to do what I wanted. I know this is probably a clumsy solution but it works. Anyone who would like to point out clumsiness is welcome.

So, first I created a user defined procedure GetMyColumns(). I cannot tell the exact purpose of the first two lines. It is just what the phpMyAdmin editor for functions added when I chose option in the editor.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`geonextp`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GetMyColumns`(`type` VARCHAR(258)) RETURNS VARCHAR(4096) CHARSET latin1 NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN
  DECLARE rownum INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE columns_string VARCHAR(4096) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE col_string VARCHAR(512);
  SET rownum = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM column_names);
  SET columns_string = '';
  WHILE counter <= rownum DO
    SET col_string = (
      SELECT `column_name` 
      FROM `column_names` 
      WHERE 
        `column_id` = counter AND 
        `column_type` = type
    );
    IF col_string IS NULL
        THEN
        SET col_string = '';
    END IF;
    IF columns_string = '' THEN
        SET columns_string = col_string;
    ELSE
        IF NOT (col_string = '')
        THEN
            SET columns_string = CONCAT(CONCAT(columns_string, ', '), col_string);
        END IF;
    END IF;
    SET counter = counter + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN columns_string;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then I added a little piece of code [A Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2325987/a-paul) suggested:

```
SET @inner_sql = GetColumns('type2');
SET @sql = CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT ', @inner_sql), ' FROM products WHERE id = 1');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

The result is exactly:

```
+-----------+--------------+
| category  | description  |
+-----------+--------------+
| category1 | description1 |
+-----------+--------------+
```

It's been an experience :)